# Retuning JObject\dynamic with ServiceStack seems to return

Tags: c#, json, json.net, servicestack

I'm trying to take a JSON string from SQL (works fine with SQL json queries, it's stuctured fine in there) and return it through ServiceStack. There's no errors on deserializing it, I can see the object in debug, but the result from the service is just a bunch of blank nested arrays?

```
//Tried both of these, same result
this.Json = JObject.Parse(json);
/// or
this.Json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

///....
public dynamic Json { get; set; }
/// or
public JObject Json { get; set; }
```

Can't do a POCO because I don't know the structure, just need to poop back out the json blob.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See [Service Return Types](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-return-types) and [Customize HTTP Responses](https://docs.servicestack.net/customize-http-responses) for different ways to return custom responses in ServiceStack.

If you just want to return the JSON from SQL Server as-is, you can return the json string with the JSON Content Type, e.g:

```cs
[AddHeader(ContentType = MimeTypes.Json)]
public string Get(RawJson request)
{
    //...
    return json;
}
```

Or use a `HttpResult` if you need to add additional HTTP Headers:

```cs
public string Get(RawJson request)
{
    return new HttpResult(json) {
        ContentType = MimeTypes.Json,
        Headers = {
            [HttpHeaders.XXX] = "..."
        }
    };

}
```

Either way you should annotate your Request DTO that it returns a string so clients know to return the string response as-is:

```cs
public class RawJson : IReturn<string> {}
```

If you want to return the JSON object as part of a larger payload you can use [JS Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/js-utils) `JSON.parse()` to parse arbitrary JSON in untyped generic collections, e.g:

```cs
public string Get(CustomJson request)
{
    return new CustomJsonResponse {
        Result = JSON.parse(json)
    };
}
```

Where `Result` is an `object`, using `object` does mean that it wont be supported with [Add ServiceStack Reference](https://docs.servicestack.net/js-utils) typed clients and clients would just need to parse it as arbitrary JSON, e.g. `JSON.parse(json)` in JavaScript.

Comment: Nothing I do seems to get it to return anything but that mess of empty arrays or the encoded string ("Json": "{\"geolocation\"). 

The issue I guess is the records in the DB are being converted to a POCO, then that is being returned by SS, not just the raw json column itself. the Id Int, Event String, Created DateTime... and then the Json String. The JSON is being flattened out a bit through sql json queries in a SP. But one of those cols is still just the raw nvarchar json string.

I can't seem to use the JS Utils because we're stuck on v5

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1HzTm4

Comment: @SteveMcNiven-Scott don't return JSON in a string property if you don't want it escaped, either return the entire JSON string or return the deserialized JSON as per my answer

Comment: I know, well like I don't want to return it as an escaped string, which is why I tried to return the JObject, but that's where the initial problem with empty array was happening. I'm telling it to use json, even with the &format=json querystring.

Comment: @SteveMcNiven-Scott has nothing to do with it, anything you return in a string property needs to be escaped, did you try returning an `object` property and `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: No I tried object with JObject.Parse (thats the above screenshot result), only ended up with string in testing because the JObject wasn't coming across.

JSON.parse just throws "Could not load type 'ServiceStack.Extensions.ServiceStackExtensions' from assembly 'ServiceStack.Text, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'.",

So I can't really test with that one

Comment: @SteveMcNiven-Scott Why? JObject is from a different serializer impl.

Comment: @SteveMcNiven-Scott check your dependencies, all ServiceStack deps should have the same version number.

Comment: OMG, this worked a charm... turns out SS.Text was 5.7 through Nuget, the rest of the solution was 5.9.2 on the other assemblies. Appreciate you sticking through this myth.